# Is there a way in Cypress of doing a reverse "getBySel" or something similar?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Cypress has numerous methods for searching deeper in the DOM for a matching element. From a certain div, I can query its children for a matching element, selector, attribute etc.

Is there a way of doing this in reverse, for the parents of an element? To use a simple example, let's say I have 4 chips, all with different text. Here's one chip:

```
<div data-test="chip">
  <div className="left">
    <p><span className="truncate">Chip 1</span></p>
  </div>
  <div className="right">
    <i onClick={handleRemove} data-test="remove-chip">X</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I want to use Cypress to remove one chip, I need to be able to tell it which 'X' to click. The easiest way would be to select all chips, match on the text, then do a reverse "get" search to match on the `data-test=chip` so that we only select 1 chip instead of all 4.

```
cy.getBySel('list-of-chips')
  .contains('Chip 1')
  .reverseGetBySel('chip') // does this exist??
  .find('[data-test="remove-chip"]')
  .click();
```

The `parentsUntil` operator doesn't work for this, since it also returns an array of all parents. I want it to do the opposite, instead of returning all parents until the provided selector, I want the selector at the end of the chain of parents. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: If I understand well, calling .parent().parent() instead of ".reverseGetBySel('chip')' should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'reverseFindBySel',
  {
    prevSubject: true, // must be chained off get or find
  },
  (subject, selector, ...args) => {
    return cy.wrap(subject).parents(`[data-test=${selector}]`, ...args);
  }
);
```